# Puzzled about DVD playback problems

Tags: vlc, dvd

I recently moved house and have no broadband, so joined a DVD rental place and find myself using my DVD player for the first time in a long time. The DVD I rented seemed to be working alright, but was skipping a bit.

Then it just stopped with about 20 minutes left. I went to the rental place and exchanged it, but the new disc stops in exactly the same place. Even trying to skip to a point after the scene where it gets stuck doesn't work, and for some chapters leading up to the point where it breaks it will get stuck in a loop showing the same chapter again and again. The timeline also seems wrong, it shows that I'm at the end of the DVD even though there should be another 30 or so minutes left.

After doing some looking around I guessed this was a problem with some corrupted file in the ~/.dvdcss folder, so I removed all references to this DVD from there. I also checked playback with another DVD that was lying around and it worked fine, smooth right up to the ending credits.

To be honest I'm going to be leaving back the DVD tomorrow morning so even an answer for this won't help me see the end of the movie, but I'd just like to see if anyone knows what's going on.

Comment: Unless the DVD with the different title was the same length, it's hard to say if it's a problem with the disc. More likely is the drive can't track when it reaches the point where it fails. Try a longer running title and see if it has problems.

Comment: I have the same problem. Same dvd work in vlc on windows. Which version of vlc do you have? I have 2.1.6. Do you still have the problem?

Comment: I don't think it was a problem with vlc, actually I think it was because I tried to play an incomplete download of the same movie and then tried to watch it on DVD. Somehow vlc must have cached the disc information from the incomplete download